# How to position check boxes under a column header vertical in angular material?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I have a angular material table with some header column. But under one header column I have some checkboxes for the name of the project.

I have it like this:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="projects">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef (mouseover)="show = true" (mouseout)="show = false" mat-sort-header i18n>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of returnProjectCodes; let i = index">
              <mat-checkbox
                (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                (change)="filterProjects($event, i, item)"
                [checked]="selected === i"
                [disabled]="isDisabled"
                >{{ item.name }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </div>
          </div>
          Project
        </th>

        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.projects }}</td>
      </ng-container>
```

But now it looks like this:

But of course the header column project has to bee positioned above the checkboxes in line with the other column headers.

So what I have change?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack-overflow can you explain what actually you want?

Comment: HI, that the column header project will be in the same line as the other header columns(Geboortedatum, Bekijk) and that the checkboxes will appear under the column header Project

Comment: Please share your working code on https://stackblitz.com/ So that we help you